# How to get current location in Nougat (7.1.1)?

Tags: android, android-gps

I am developing one android application in that i am getting current location of user, following code work fine in below 7.1.1 version of android but not working on 7.1.1, i am getting null for location

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders();
            Location location = null;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25)
            {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }

            else {
                for (String str : providers) {

                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(str);
                    if (location != null)
                        break;
                }
            }
```

how do i get current location in android 7.1.1 version?

Comment: do you have permissions? also why not use `FusedLocationProvider`?

Comment: have you taken runtime permission?

Comment: allready gave permission when application install in mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `FusedLocationProvider` like @thepoosh said.

- This give you less batterydrain, and easier use!

Here is a reference with all the info about the [FusedLocationProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).

**Permission in the manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**Runtime permissions:** (this is the code I use -> not the cleanest but it should help you start...)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                //Here is your location result
            }
        };
        mLocationRequest = LocationHelper.createLocationRequest();
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (LocationHelper.checkLocationPermissions(this)) {
            startGps();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            View container = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            DialogHelper.showSnackbar(this, R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted.");
                startGps();
            } else {
                // Permission denied.

                // Notify the user via a SnackBar that they have rejected a core permission for the
                // app, which makes the Activity useless. In a real app, core permissions would
                // typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

                // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
                // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
                // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
                // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
                // touches or interactions which have required permissions.

                //TODO: SHOW SNACKBAR

            }
        }
    }

    private void startGps()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Setting up location services...");
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null).addOnSuccessListener(this).addOnFailureListener(this);
    }
}
```

**The LocationHelper:**

```
public class LocationHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationHelper";
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 4000;
    private static final int FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2000;

    public static LocationRequest createLocationRequest()
    {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        return locationRequest;
    }

    public static boolean checkLocationPermissions(Context context) {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: `//Start-GPS` you left out the most important part

Comment: @TimCastelijns I will add this in a sec then

Comment: @TimCastelijns this should be everything

Comment: it gives me error in LocationHelper, LocationServices,DialogHelper

Comment: @pravinmaske I added the locationhelper class and also removed the snackbarhelper (you should put your own snackbar in there as a message when the user declines the permission). I have everything separated in my project so srry that I forgot this part.